# Prove $π(x+y)- π(x) \ll \frac y{\log (\log (y))}$ using Legendre sieve such that $10 ≤ y ≤ x$

Tags: logarithms, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

How to prove $$π(x+y)- π(x)  \ll \frac y{\log (\log (y))}$$ using Legendre sieve such that $10 ≤ y ≤ x$?